# Any implication of using "that" instead of "The" in this headline?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

In this HeadLine:

"lace, **that** most coveted textile"

the way i would have tought if writing this would be:

"lace, **the** most coveted textile"

using "That" feels to me the author wants to inply something I don't get

so the question is: is there any special meaning using "that" or could it be replaced with "the" without problem?

Comment: That: _used to refer to a person, object, event, etc., separated from the speaker by distance or time, or to something that has been referred to before, **or to point to a particular thing**_  Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: It's implied that the reader knows that lace is a resource of value. "lace, that most coveted textile - you know, that [delicate fabric made of yarn or thread in an open weblike pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lace), *that* lace!"

Answer (score 20):

There are two important differences.

The first is that in the original headline with "that", "most" is an adverb meaning "very", so it means lace is *a very coveted textile*, not necessarily number one. But in your version, "*the most coveted*" forms *a superlative adjective* meaning lace is *the number one* textile in terms of how coveted it is. Since it doesn't make a lot of sense to rank textiles according to how coveted they are, "the" is probably wrong, and certainly doesn't have the same meaning as the original.

The other difference is that "that" implies *the reader already knows* lace is a highly coveted textile. It means something like, "*lace, the textile **that we all know** is highly coveted,*" whereas without "that" it sounds like the speaker is asserting something to the reader: "Lace *is* a highly coveted textile".

To use "most" in the sense of "very", but not suggest the reader already knows lace is very coveted, you can use "a":

> Lace, a most coveted textile

Comment: It's like saying "Tom? That idiot?"

Comment: @RedSonja Depends how you mean "that". Do you mean, "*Tom? **The person that we all know** is an idiot?*", or do you mean, "*Tom? The idiot that's standing **over there**?*"

Comment: Good point. Both. Depends how you say it. The first you just say, because we all know who and that he's an idiot. The second you might point to him, that Tom over there, not this one. They might both be idiots...

Comment: @RedSonja In the first sense, yes, I believe it's the same "that". No to the second one, where "that" is used to indicate a particular person, rather than suggest common knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather poetic and old-fashioned use of *that*.  The meaning is

[> 1 b. being the one specified -> usually used for emphasis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that)

So yes, the meaning is essentially the same as "lace, the most coveted textile", but the author is using *that* to call emphasis to the phrase.  It's a little like "lace, which is that specific textile which is most coveted."

Comment: I don't know if I agree this use of "that" is poetic or old-fashioned; almost everything *else* in the OP's example seems overwrought, but the use of "that" itself seems normal to me. Specifically, it seems the same as the use in "It was that guy down the street who's always yelling at his TV."

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me.  The word _most_ in _"the most coveted textile"_ is superlative - it means there's nothing else that's more coveted than lace.  But in _"that most coveted textile"_, the word _most_ is not a superlative - it just means _very_ or _highly_; that is, although lace is highly coveted, there may be something else that's even more coveted.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Agreed – an equivalent usage of *most* would be as in "It is **a most** excellent specimen". Simply that you can use *most* with the indefinite article here indicates that it's not a superlative. Nothing is implied about how excellent the specimen is with respect to others, and it's the same in the OP's headline. But I do agree with this answer that it sounds a bit archaic.